# In Typescipt, how can I filter on the first unique object encountered in an array of objects?

Tags: json, typescript

I have an array of JSON objects as follow, and I want to read through it, find the first instance of the appname, eg 'app1', 'app2', and store the whole object for each...

```
 myArray[
{
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app1",
        "servername": "randomname-xyx",
        "status": "DOWN"
      }
    },
    {
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app1",
        "servername": "another-random-name",
        "status": "DOWN"
      }
    },
    {
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app2",
        "servername": "some-server",
        "status": "UP"
      }
    },
    {
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app2",
        "servername": "abc-server",
        "status": "DOWN"
      }
    },
    {
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app2",
        "servername": "qwerty-srv",
        "status": "DOWN"
      }
    },
    {
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app2",
        "servername": "last-server",
        "status": "UP"
      }
    },
]
```

At the moment, I have this...

```
this.getAppClient.getFullList()
    .subscribe((apps) => {
      this.applicationList = [...new Map(apps.myArray.map((o: { myApp: { appname: any; }; })=>[o.myApp.appname, o])).values()]
    })
```

...which is filtering for unique objects by appname but is returning the last object for each appname instead of the first, so I'm getting this...

```
{
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app1",
        "servername": "another-random-name",
        "status": "DOWN"
      }
    },
{
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app2",
        "servername": "last-server",
        "status": "UP"
      }
    },
```

...when I want this...

```
{
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app1",
        "servername": "randomname-xyx",
        "status": "DOWN"
      }
    },
 {
      "myApp": {
        "appname": "app2",
        "servername": "some-server",
        "status": "UP"
      }
    }
```

Is it possible to modify my filter to pick up the objects in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
const tmpAppName = new Set<string>();
const result: any[] = [];
myArray.forEach(el => {
  if(!tmpAppName.has(el.myApp.appname)) {
    tmpAppName.add(el.myApp.appname);
    result.push(el);
  }
})
console.log(result);
```

Output

```
[{
  "myApp": {
    "appname": "app1",
    "servername": "randomname-xyx",
    "status": "DOWN"
  }
}, {
  "myApp": {
    "appname": "app2",
    "servername": "some-server",
    "status": "UP"
  }
}]
```

Comment: If you've got a lot of different appnames this is going to be slow because it is scanning through tmpAppName each time. You could replace tmpAppName with a set.

Comment: Updated with a set.

Comment: That's perfect - it got me exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot. I'm not too worried about the speed of the response too much for now, but I'll consider using a set later if needed.